# how to exclude some routes when user is not logged in zfcuser?

Tags: php, zend-framework, zend-framework2, zfcuser

So, i am new in Zend Framework, i installed **ZfcUser** and i want when the user is not logged to didn't access to some routes for example : /blog/article/add,

actually i use `<?php if($this->zfcUserIdentity()) :?>` to check if the user is logged but how can i redirect the user to my login route`/user` if is try to access to /blog/article/add,
so plz if someone has any idea i will be very appreciative :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Simple Way:

in controller:

```
if (!$this->zfcUserAuthentication()->hasIdentity()) {
    return $this->redirect()->toRoute('route_to_login',array('param' => $param));
}
```

Some more:
(after auth zfcuset will redirect you to previous controller)

in module.config.php

```
'controllers' => array(
    'invokables' => array(
        'zfcuser' => 'Application\Controller\UserController',
    ),
...
),
```

next copy file vendor\zf-commons\zfc-user\src\ZfcUser\Controller\UserController.php
to module Application (same folder as in module.config.php)

delete all function except authenticateAction
add:
    use Zend\Session\Container;
and change 
`return $this->redirect()->toRoute($this->getOptions()->getLoginRedirectRoute());`
to

```
$redirect_session = new Container('redirect');
        $redirect = $redirect_session->redirect;
        if($redirect!='')
        {
            unset($_SESSION['redirect']);
            return $this->redirect()->toRoute($redirect, array('lang' => $lang));
        }
        return $this->redirect()->toRoute($this->getOptions()->getLoginRedirectRoute(),array('param' => $param));
```

and at last add in controller

```
use Zend\Session\Container;
...
if (!$this->zfcUserAuthentication()->hasIdentity()) {
            $redirect_session = new Container('redirect');
            $redirect_session->redirect = 'route_to_this_controller_action';
            return $this->redirect()->toRoute('route_to_login',array('param' => $param));
        }
```

Answer (score 4):

I disagree with the selected answer because it's not really practical to do these kind of things inside every action of every controller that you want to deny access to.

There are two big modules out there that are used for this task. The first one being [`BjyAuthorize`](https://github.com/bjyoungblood/BjyAuthorize) and the other big one being [`ZfcRbac`](https://github.com/ZF-Commons/zfc-rbac). Please check them out. ZfcRbac is my favorite (because i wrote documentation for it) but it requires PHP 5.4+

Comment: Thnx @Sam i appreciate your answer, yes i am agree with u i can't do the same thing in every action,